# From IOT hub to multiple tables in an Azure SQL database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub, azure-stream-analytics

I have an IOT hub with devices that push their sensor data to it, to be stored in a SQL database. This seems to be quite easy to do by means of a Stream Analytics job.

However, the tricky part is as follows. The data I'm pushing is not normalized, and since I'm using a SQL database I would like to structure it among multiple tables. This does not seem to be an easy task with Stream Analytics.

This is an example of the payload I'm pushing to the IOT hub:

```
{
    "timestamp" : "2019-01-10 12:00",
    "section" : 1,
    "measurements" : 
    {
        "temperature" : 28.7,
        "height" : 280,
        "ec" : 6.8
    },
    "pictures" : {
        "101_a.jpg",
        "102_b.jpg",
        "103_c.jpg"
    }
}
```

My database has a table *Measurement*, *MeasurementItem* and *Picture*. I would like to store the timestamp and section in a *Measurement* record, the temperature, height and ec in a *MeasurementItem* record and the pictures in the *Picture* table. 
Filling one table is easy, but to fill the second table I need the generated auto-increment ID of the previous record to keep the relation intact.

Is that actually possible with Stream Analytics, and if no, how should I do that?

Comment: You could write a view with an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger in SQL to insert the values in various tables.

Comment: If maintaining a common key is the only requirement, and a non auto increment key is an option , you could create a unique id column as part of your stream analytics job. However, please note thar you would do this with multiple stream analytics output, and each output will progress independently. As david Browne pointed out, inserting into a view that triggers an insert to multiple tables is an option. Please validate if the perf implications of this is ok for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with an Azure function with an IoT hub trigger. The function uses EF Core to store the JSON messages in the SQL database, spread over multiple tables. I was a bit reluctant for this approach, as it introduces extra logic and I expected to pay extra for that.

The opposite appeared to be true. For Azure Functions, the first 400,000 GB/s of execution and 1,000,000 executions are free. Moreover, this solution gives extra flexibility and control because the single table limitation does no longer apply.

[image: Azure function costs]

Answer (score 2):

You should'nt try it with Stream Analytics (SA) for several reasons. It's not designed for workloads like this, because otherwise SA would not be able to perform it's work this performant. It's just sending data to one or more sinks depending on input data.

I would suggest passing the data to a component that is able to perform logic on the output-side. There are a some options for this. 2 examples might be:

- `Azure Function` (via service-bus-trigger pointing to the IoT hub built-in endpoint as described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/how-to-use-azure-functions-with-iot-hub-message-routing/))
- Event-Grid-based trigger on a storage you write the IoT data to (so again you could use a Azure Function but let it be triggered by an event from a storage account)

This solutions also come with the price that each incoming data package will call a logic unit for which you have to pay additionally. Be aware that there are billing options on Azure Functions that will not depend on the amount of calls but provide you the logic in a more app-service-like model.

If you have huge amounts of data to process you might consider an architecture using [Data Lake Storage Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-portal) in combination with [Data Lake Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/) instead. The latter can collect, aggregate and distribute your incoming data into different data stores too.